# Unity build issue -photonView change names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I got this attentions.

**On the first warning :** Connection.cs(9,23).I have this code :

```
public class MenuMultiplayer : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
```

Should I change the word  MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks to MonoBehaviourPun.photonView

**On the second warning**: MenuMultiplayer(24,23): I have this code:

```
[Header("Components")]
    public PhotonView photonView;
```

Should I change the word photonView to MonoBehaviourPun.photonView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you need this for `public PhotonView photonView;`? The `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` already provides its own view via a same named property which is what the warning is telling you

Comment: @derHugo I am creating a menu

Comment: so .. ? This doesn't explain what exactly you need this field for .. as said if it is just in order to reference the own `PhotonView` of that object -> you don't need it, rather use the already existing property of `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`

Comment: In general though: Why is your menu a `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`? Is this supposed to be synchronized in any way? I would expect a menu be only local for your local player and it is rather the player that is synchronized

Comment: @derHugo ok thank you I go try it :)

Comment: yes it is gone :) thank you man!